# Flutter : What are the differences between Flutter Plugin, Flutter Package and Flutter Module?

Tags: android-studio, dart, sdk, flutter

[image]

on selecting `Create New Flutter Project` in android Studio and there appear 4 choices for that as below.

[image]

- `Flutter Application`
- `Flutter Plugin`
- `Flutter Package`
- `Flutter Module`

What is the difference between all these Flutter project types

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Flutter Application: A standalone, fully-functional Flutter application.
2. Flutter Plugin: A plugin is a kind of bridge that you develop between a native feature like camera API in Android and iOS.
3. Flutter Package: A package is a flutter application written solely using Dart. It doesn't have much to do with the Native functionalities.
4. Flutter Module: A module is a set of functionalities that you want to use in your app. It is a custom code that does a specific task but can be used for other apps in the future. So, you keep it handy.

P. S.: Android already gave each description in short. In the last screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are for *creating* the Flutter SDK.  They all *use* the SDK to create plugins, packages, and modules.  The text on your screen describes the differences.

I suspect the company is asking you to build a Flutter *Application* as a demonstration (*using* the Flutter SDK).

Comment: Well, the actual description is “ Build an efficient, lightweight, and high performance client side SDK “. What does it mean then?

Comment: It's just HR-speak.  It means nothing.  You need to talk to someone technical that isn't just quoting buzzwords.  There isn't any way you're building an SDK in any short time.

Comment: I just want to get an overview about it.

Comment: what do you mean "overview" and "it"?  Hard to know what will satisfy that.